# Ajuda com Trigger que soma/subtrai

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Preciso de ajuda para criar um Trigger no SQL Server que pega um valor `INTEIRO`, e dois `STRING(FK)`, inseridos em uma `tabela X`, e checar se o segundo valor for `1` ou `2`, se for `1` ela deve somar esse valor `INTEIRO` com um valor `INTEIRO` de outra `Tabela Y` que possui a `STRING(FK)` como `PK`, e se a primeira `String` for `2` ao invés de somar ela deve subtrair do mesmo local.

Estou com muita dificuldade na lógica e na estrutura do Trigger. Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

**DETALHAMENTO**  (a partir de comentário do autor)
São duas tabelas: `Conta` e `Transação`.
A tabela `Conta` possui a coluna `saldo` e a tabela `Transação` possui as colunas `valorDaTransacao`, `tipoTransacao` (1 para saque e 0 para depósito) e `numeroConta`, que é chave estrangeira apontando para a tabela `Conta`.
Sempre que for criada uma nova linha na tabela `Transação`, o procedimento *trigger* deve ser disparado, subtraindo ou adicionando `valorTransacao` na coluna `saldo` da tabela `Conta`.

Comment: Poderia ampliar a descrição do problema? Me parece ainda um pouco confuso. Acrescente nomes das tabelas e das colunas envolvidas bem como as tabelas X e Y se relacionam. E também exemplo.

Comment: Coloque a estrutura das tabelas e o código que já tem pronto

Comment: Dica , use o CASE ...  ((CASE WHEN X = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) * Y)

Comment: Olá galera, desculpe! S]ão duas tabelas, Tabela Conta e Tabela Transação. A Tabela Conta possui em uma de suas colunas, a coluna SALDO, e na Tabela Transação possui uma coluna valorDaTransacao. Na Tabela Transacao, existe uma FK (numeroConta) que é PK(numeroConta) na tabela Conta, e também uma coluna (tipoTransacao) que pode ser 1 (SAQUE) ou 0 (DEPOSITO). Meu objetivo ´é que sempre que criado um novo registro na Tabela Transação, um Trigger seja disparado, SUBTRAINDO ou ADICIONANDO o valorTransacao na coluna Saldo da Tabela Conta. Melhor descrito agr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O procedimento *trigger* então é para monitorar a inclusão de linhas na tabela Transacao.

```
-- código #1 v2
CREATE TRIGGER incTransacao_Conta
    on Transacao 
    after INSERT as
begin
-- encerra o processamento se não há linha para tratar
IF not exists (SELECT * from INSERTED) return;
--
UPDATE C
  set saldo+= case I.tipoTransacao 
                   when 1 then -I.valorDaTransacao 
                   when 0 then I.valorDaTransacao 
                   else 0 end
  from Conta as C 
       inner join INSERTED as I on I.numeroConta = C.numeroConta;
end;
```

Sugestão de leitura:

- [CREATE TRIGGER](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)
- [Estudo de casos de tópicos do fórum relacionados a procedimentos trigger](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/37857.t-sql-estudo-de-casos-de-topicos-do-forum-technet-relacionados-a-procedimentos-trigger.aspx)
- [Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/08/18/armadilhas-na-programacao-de-trigger/)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Consegui criar a Trigger, usei esse código: